# UnsupportedOperationException using Ajax.update or getRenderIds().add

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, partial-page-refresh, omnifaces

I'm trying to refresh a jsf component using java code. First, i try using this :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("MyCompId");
```

but it produce an "UnsupportedOperationException". Then, i try to install omnifaces and use Ajax.update("MyComp"). The result is the same :

```
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1041)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:289)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1415)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:765)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:303)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:291)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:221)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Ajax.update(Ajax.java:75)
```

I try to reproduce the same example found here : http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Ajax.
My XHTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<f:view  contentType="text/html">
    <h:body id="body">
        <h:form id="form">
            <div id="contentStyle">    
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="blocLsMsgErr" id="messages">
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="lsMsgErr">
                        <h:dataTable var="facesMessage"
                            value="#{messagesComponent.listeCustomFacesMessage1}">
                            <h:column>
                                <h:graphicImage alt="icon"
                                    value="/images/messages/#{facesMessage.severity}_icon.png" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputLink rendered="#{not empty facesMessage.id}"
                                    styleClass="titre #{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('#{facesMessage.id}').focus();return false;">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{facesMessage.summary} " />
                                </h:outputLink>
                                <h:outputText rendered="#{empty facesMessage.id}"
                                    styleClass="titre #{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value="#{facesMessage.summary} " />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="#{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value=" -1- " />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <h:outputText styleClass="#{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value="#{facesMessage.detail}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <ui:repeat value="#{messagesComponent.listeCustomFacesMessage2}"
                                var="facesMessage">
                                <h:graphicImage alt="icon"
                                    value="/images/messages/#{facesMessage.severity}_icon.png" />
                                <h:outputLink rendered="#{not empty facesMessage.id}"
                                    styleClass="titre #{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('#{facesMessage.id}').focus();return false;">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{facesMessage.summary} " />
                                </h:outputLink>
                                <h:outputText rendered="#{empty facesMessage.id}"
                                    styleClass="titre #{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value="#{facesMessage.summary} " />
                                <h:outputText styleClass="#{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value=" -2- " />
                                <h:outputText styleClass="#{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value="#{facesMessage.detail}" />
                                <br />
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                            <c:forEach items="#{messagesComponent.listeCustomFacesMessage3}"
                                var="facesMessage">
                                <h:graphicImage alt="icon"
                                    value="/images/messages/#{facesMessage.severity}_icon.png" />
                                <h:outputLink rendered="#{not empty facesMessage.id}"
                                    styleClass="titre #{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    onclick="document.getElementById('#{facesMessage.id}').focus();return false;">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{facesMessage.summary} " />
                                </h:outputLink>
                                <h:outputText rendered="#{empty facesMessage.id}"
                                    styleClass="titre #{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value="#{facesMessage.summary} " />
                                <h:outputText styleClass="#{facesMessage.severity}"
                                    value=" -3- " />
                                <h:panelGroup>
                                    <h:outputText styleClass="#{facesMessage.severity}"
                                        value="#{facesMessage.detail}" />
                                    <br />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <ui:insert name="content" />

                <h:commandButton styleClass="button"
                    value="#{messages.boutonSuivant}" id="buttonNext"
                    action="#{testBean.nextPage}">
                    <f:ajax />
                </h:commandButton>
            </div>
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{testBean.update}">
                <f:ajax />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

My Bean :

```
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.omnifaces.util.Ajax;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Named
@Scope("session")
public class TestBean {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void update() {
        System.out.println("Ajax update");
        Ajax.update("messages");
        System.out.println("Ajax update OK");
    }

    public String nextPage() {

        if (!this.validationChampsPagePersonne()) {
            return null;

        }

        return "next";
    }

    private boolean validationChampsPagePersonne() {
    //doing a FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    }

}
```

Other informations : 
I'm using myfaces api and implementation (version 2.1.11), trinidad 2.1.0, tomahawk2 1.1.14, primefaces 3.5

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyFaces can't be the cause, it has always worked in MyFaces for us and anyone else. We have however never really used Trinidad, so I took a look in the Trinidad source code. It [appears](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.trinidad/trinidad-impl/2.0.1/org/apache/myfaces/trinidadinternal/context/PartialViewContextImpl.java#PartialViewContextImpl._getIds%28java.lang.String%29) that it returns `Collections#emptySet()` when there are no render IDs. This is however [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet%28%29)! This totally explains the exception you're facing.

This is a rather astonishing bug in Trinidad. The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#getRenderIds%28%29) clearly says that the returned collection must be mutable.

> Return a `Collection` of client identifiers from the current request with the request parameter name `PARTIAL_RENDER_PARAM_NAME`. If there is no such request parameter, return an empty `Collection`. These client identifiers are used to identify components that will be processed during the render phase of the request processing lifecycle. **The returned `Collection` is mutable.**

If you like Trinidad, report it as a bug to the Trinidad guys. Otherwise just get rid of it. I don't see any reason to use it if you're already using PrimeFaces (and Tomahawk).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll report a bug to Trinidad. We are using Trinidad from beginning and use a lot of their components, so it's difficult to stop using it!